# How to include an XAML icon in another XAML file

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've downloaded the [Visual Studio Image Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825), which contains XAML icons. For example, this is the content of the file `FolderClosed_16x.xaml`:

```
<!-- This file was generated by the AiToXaml tool.-->
<!-- Tool Version: 14.0.22307.0 -->
<Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <DrawingBrush>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
          <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
              <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M0,0L16,0 16,16 0,16z" />
              <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M1.5,1L9.61,1 10.61,3 13.496,3C14.323,3,14.996,3.673,14.996,4.5L14.996,12.5C14.996,13.327,14.323,14,13.496,14L1.5,14C0.673,14,0,13.327,0,12.5L0,2.5C0,1.673,0.673,1,1.5,1" />
              <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M1.9998,3.0004L1.9998,4.0004 8.8738,4.0004 8.3738,3.0004z" />
              <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFDBB679" Geometry="F1M2,3L8.374,3 8.874,4 2,4z M13.496,4L10,4 9.992,4 8.992,2 1.5,2C1.225,2,1,2.224,1,2.5L1,12.5C1,12.776,1.225,13,1.5,13L13.496,13C13.773,13,13.996,12.776,13.996,12.5L13.996,4.5C13.996,4.224,13.773,4,13.496,4" />
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
          </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
      </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
</Viewbox>
```

I've added this file to my project in Visual Studio. How do I use the icon in another XAML file? Pasting these lines inside my XAML file works as expected, but I'd like to keep all icon files in a directory and reference them in multiple places. Is this possible without modifying the icon files?

I'd like to use it like this in my `MainWindow.xaml`, but this doesn't work:

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Icons/FolderClosed_16x.xaml}" />
```

Comment: You have to add it to a resource dictionary and give it a x:Key then you can add it to the Content of the contentControl. eg. x:Key="MyViewBox" <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyViewBox}".  For more example, see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Can you give an example of a resource dictionary that references an xaml file? The link you provided doesn't have such an example. Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: A resource dictionary is a xaml file.  But you can load a file isn't actually part of your project or compiled into it at run time.  Microsoft binned their technet gallery so the linked samples won't work but this describes one way to load an uncompiled xaml file off disk at run time. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28797.wpf-dynamic-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the `Viewbox` as a type or resource.

1. Create new `UserControl´ (Project->Add user Control (WPF) in Visual Studio) called FolderClosed_16x.
2. Replace the contents of the FolderClosed_16x.xaml file with this:

   ```
    <Viewbox x:Class="WpfApp1.FolderClosed_16x"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="16" Height="16">
        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <DrawingBrush>
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M0,0L16,0 16,16 0,16z" />
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M1.5,1L9.61,1 10.61,3 13.496,3C14.323,3,14.996,3.673,14.996,4.5L14.996,12.5C14.996,13.327,14.323,14,13.496,14L1.5,14C0.673,14,0,13.327,0,12.5L0,2.5C0,1.673,0.673,1,1.5,1" />
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M1.9998,3.0004L1.9998,4.0004 8.8738,4.0004 8.3738,3.0004z" />
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFDBB679" Geometry="F1M2,3L8.374,3 8.874,4 2,4z M13.496,4L10,4 9.992,4 8.992,2 1.5,2C1.225,2,1,2.224,1,2.5L1,12.5C1,12.776,1.225,13,1.5,13L13.496,13C13.773,13,13.996,12.776,13.996,12.5L13.996,4.5C13.996,4.224,13.773,4,13.496,4" />
                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Viewbox>
   ```
3. Change the base type in FolderClosed_16x.xaml.cs to `Viewbox`:

   ```
    public partial class FolderClosed_16x : Viewbox
    {
        public FolderClosed_16x()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
   ```
4. Reference the control as usual from another view:

   ```
    <local:FolderClosed_16x />
   ```

Comment: Thank you! This works and answers the question. Since I'm new to WPF, I'm wondering if this is a good way to do it in your opinion. I didn't expect that I have to create a C# class for each icon.  Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: The other more common option is to define the `ViewBox` as a resource with an `x:Key` in a `ResourceDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I ended up using. I have one xaml file in my project that contains all the icons and they all have an `x:Key`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   
    <!-- Folder Closed -->
    <Rectangle x:Key="FolderClosed" Width="16" Height="16" x:Shared="false">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <DrawingBrush>
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#00FFFFFF" Geometry="F1M0,0L16,0 16,16 0,16z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFF6F6F6" Geometry="F1M1.5,1L9.61,1 10.61,3 13.496,3C14.323,3,14.996,3.673,14.996,4.5L14.996,12.5C14.996,13.327,14.323,14,13.496,14L1.5,14C0.673,14,0,13.327,0,12.5L0,2.5C0,1.673,0.673,1,1.5,1" />
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFEFEFF0" Geometry="F1M1.9998,3.0004L1.9998,4.0004 8.8738,4.0004 8.3738,3.0004z" />
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFDBB679" Geometry="F1M2,3L8.374,3 8.874,4 2,4z M13.496,4L10,4 9.992,4 8.992,2 1.5,2C1.225,2,1,2.224,1,2.5L1,12.5C1,12.776,1.225,13,1.5,13L13.496,13C13.773,13,13.996,12.776,13.996,12.5L13.996,4.5C13.996,4.224,13.773,4,13.496,4" />
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

    <!-- more icons go here -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In a file that uses the icon, I reference my icons file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Icons.xaml"/>
            <!-- other files can be referenced here -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- other resources can be defined here here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And in the same file, I use the icon like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource FolderClosed}" />
```